# How to run a linker script for GCC

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I'm trying to run a simple linker script to understand how linking works and how i can implement function reordering with the linker script

Here is my C code

```
void A(){
        printf("A\n");
}

void B(){
        printf("B\n");
}

void main(){
        B();
        A();
}
```

Here is the linker script

```
SECTIONS
     {
       . = 0x10000;
       .text : { *(.text) }
       . = 0x8000000;
       .data : { *(.data) }
       .bss : { *(.bss) }
     }
```

When i try to compile with this external linker script it gives me this error

```
/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/usr/bin/ld: cl: hidden symbol `__init_array_end' isn't defined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My compile command is this

```
gcc -Wl,-no-whole-archive -ffunction-sections -T simple.ld cache_ex.c -o cl
```

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MichaelPetch As the tag and the source shows, this is C, not C++.

Comment: You need some space for the string literals and other supporting stuff. Link with the default script and let the linker write a map file. Investigate that. Or use `objdump` to look into a built executable to learn about the sections needed for a complete program.

Comment: Did you manage to build normally? I.e. without special linking goals.